# How to select an option in angular js when options are fetched from an api

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a app that has connected select box like state,city.
now i have to feed the state name and city name from controller.
I am not able to find out the way.

```
<label>State</label>
                <select ng-change="cities(state);" class="form-control" ng-model="state" required>
                    <option selected>Select</option>
                    <option  ng-repeat="x in state" value="{{x.State}}">{{x.State}}
                    </option>

                </select>
                <label>City</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-change="location(city);" required>
                    <option selected>Select</option>
                    <option  ng-repeat="y in cities" value="{{y.city}}">{{y.city}}
                    </option>
                </select>
```

I tried this code in controller but does not work.

```
     $scope.state=response.data.State;
     $scope.city=response.date.Cities;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are use `state` as `ngModel` and as well as with `ngRepeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign ng-repeat array with different name:

```
$scope.states=response.data.State;
 $scope.cities=response.date.Cities;
```

Need to have ng-model of select in different name:

```
<label>State</label>
                <select ng-change="cities(state);" class="form-control" ng-model="state" required>
                    <option selected>Select</option>
                    <option  ng-repeat="x in states" value="{{x.State}}">{{x.State}}
                    </option>

                </select>
                <label>City</label>
                <select class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-change="location(city);" required>
                    <option selected>Select</option>
                    <option  ng-repeat="y in cities" value="{{y.city}}">{{y.city}}
                    </option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also,It can be achieved by using **ng-options**

Let Controller be:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.States = [
{"Name":"Value 1","ID":1},
{"Name":"Value 2","ID":2},
{"Name":"Value 3","ID":3},
{"Name":"Value 4","ID":4}
];

   $scope.Cities = [
{"Name":"Value 1","ID":1},
{"Name":"Value 2","ID":2},
{"Name":"Value 3","ID":3},
{"Name":"Value 4","ID":4}
];

$scope.selectedState=2; //setting default select
$scope.selectedCity=4;
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-options="value.ID as value.Name for value in States" 
    ng-model="selectedState" ></select>
    Selected state is : {{selectedState}}
    <hr>
     <select ng-options="value.ID as value.Name for value in Cities" 
    ng-model="selectedCity" ></select>
    Selected city is : {{selectedCity}}
  </body>
```

Working Plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/AjshYsWau2ucszOt1Zhg?p=preview)

For different ways of selecting drop down see plunker [click here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m4ov2ANe8uT7sphu48EQ?p=preview)